# Laravel5 Helping build query syntax

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

can someone advice me what to do ? 
I have 2 columns - `price` and `discount_price`. Many values of the column `discount_price` can be `NULL`.
I want to show `discount_price` if it's value is `NULL` in database, or the the `price` will be shown to the customers.
It should almost like this if statement:

```
if($discount_price != NULL) {
    return $discount_price
}
else {
    return $price
}
```

Here is my query, it doesn't work correctly:

```
$products = Product_Lang::select(\DB::raw('products_lang.*'))
            ->join('products', 'products_lang.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->join('category_product', 'products.id', '=', 'category_product.product_id')
            ->where('language_code', App::getLocale())
            ->where('display', 1)
            ->where('category_id', $category->id)
            ->selectRaw('CONCAT(name, " ", model) AS product_name, products.id')
            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(discount_price, price) AS product_price')
            ->orderBy($sortby, $order)
            ->paginate(50);
```

Comment: What is not working on this query? An error is returned?

Comment: There are no errors, but it only returns discount_price column, so I get empty values as well, but I need price column values instead to blanks.

Comment: I suggest you to check the last executed query (`$queries = DB::getQueryLog(); $last_query = end($queries);`) in order to get the SQL and check if your query is working ad expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `discount_price` field's value is `NULL` not just an empty field. `COALESCE` will return a empty value if your field value is empty, it will work only when your field value is `Null`.

If it solves this way, make your `discount_price` default value to 'NULL' in database.

Comment: Yeap, thank you, that was the problem, didn't had NULL in table.